# Differential of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is a way in order to reproduce this graphic in with tikzpicture? Which is the best way?

[image]

Comment: use the `pgfplots` package

Comment: See also [Plot to illustrate secant lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168297).

Comment: Again a  "DO-IT-FOR-ME" question. (1) Please show us what you've tried.  I miss a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).